# Off-canvas menu layout breaks because of canvas on iOS

Tags: javascript, css, ios

Like in the title, the off-canvas menu works fine on pc/android, but z-index has issues on iOS. Do you have any good workaround? WordPress - neve theme, but I'm mostly styling in CSS.

text

I tried with sticky positioning, but it's not working here. I want to keep that canvas with animation on this site and fix the menu displaying. Thanks for your help!

Comment: liquidmaster.pl

Comment: [link](https://liquidmaster.pl)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling sliding from left resolved issue.